# javascript function overloading operation details

Tags: javascript

I read Jhon resig post about function overloading:

http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-method-overloading/

The functions:

```
function Users(){
  addMethod(this, "find", function(){
    // Find all users...
  });
  addMethod(this, "find", function(name){
    // Find a user by name
  });
  addMethod(this, "find", function(first, last){
    // Find a user by first and last name
  });
}

// addMethod - By John Resig (MIT Licensed)
function addMethod(object, name, fn){
    var old = object[ name ];
    object[ name ] = function(){
        if ( fn.length == arguments.length )
            return fn.apply( this, arguments );
        else if ( typeof old == 'function' )
            return old.apply( this, arguments );
    };
}
```

I understand the concept. The one thing I can't understand is why each time the `else if` statement is executing the `return old.apply(this, arguments)` the arguments length is decremented by one.

I used alerts to follow the function and that is the main thing I can't understand.

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: It's decremented because this is how it's written. The third `find` implementation takes 3 arguments, the second takes 2, and the first can be called without any parameter. Make the third implementation take 5 parameters, and the second 3 - and it will decrement by 2 :)

Comment: MikeM : 

function (){
        if ( fn.length == arguments.length )
            return fn.apply( this, arguments );
        else if ( typeof old == 'function' )
{alert("fn:" + fn.length + "    arguments:" + arguments.length);

            return old.apply( this, arguments );
}
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It effectively results in a chain of `old` functions that are called one after the other until one whose arity matched `arguments.length` is found. So on the first call to `addMethod`, you'll end up with `old` being `undefined`.

The 2nd time you call `addMethod`, `old` will end up being the function that was assigned in during the first call.

If you run this:

```
var users = new Users();
users.find("James");
```

It will look for a property of `users` with the identifier `find`. It will find one, and the arity of that function will be 2 (because the final call to `addMethod` in the constructor creates a method that expects 2 arguments). So instead of calling that, it calls `old`, which will be the version of the method that expects 1 argument. Our invocation has a single argument, and that matches, so that's the method that gets executed.

If you run this:

```
users.find();
```

It will do exactly what I described above, but when it calls `old` the arity will not match and it will call `old` again. The value of `old` in this situation will be what it was after the first call to `addMethod` (that's a demonstration of a thing usually referred to as a closure - the old `old` function is still available after the parent function has returned).

Comment: If I understand correctly, find(arg1, arg2) has property with old defiend as find(arg1, arg2)

find(arg1) has old property difined as find()

And find() has old property as undefind

Is that correct?

Comment: Yes I think you get it, although you made a slight mistake in your comment - `find(a1, a2)` has its `old` property as `find(a1)` effectively.

Comment: Note that the "decrement" you mention is just a side-effect of the fact that `addMethod` in this case has been called 3 times, with an incrementing number of arguments each time.